# LED matrix simulation

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, actionscript, tween

I never really write much actionscript let alone as3. 
I've run into a little problem and would like to ask for ideas or help.

I am trying to simulate a LED matrix of 40x40 LEDs, that are supposed to blink at slightly different intervals including fade out.
I use an array for new sprites and write the 40x40 to screen - applying various tweens in the process. Event listeners are supposed to restart the tweens, so they would loop at the various tween intervals set in the 'for' loop.

task complete: this is what i came up with. it's pretty cost intensive with the number of eventlisteners. cpu temp will increase slightly but it works. still interested in a more efficient way of doing similar animation. pls grant me that i'm not really familiar with as3.
mistake seems to have been the call to tween in the onFinish function. should have been e.target.yoyo() instead of the array element.

```
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var stageWidth: Number = stage.stageWidth;
var n: Number = 40; //matrix width and height
var nsquare: Number = (n * n);
var segment: Number = stageWidth / n; //stage diveded by matrix n
var dot_items: Array = [];
var tweens: Array = [];
var basetime: int = 1; //transition base time ..add half basetime random for various transition speed.

for (var l: int = 0; l < n; l++) {
    for (var i: int = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var count: Number = (l * n) + i;
        dot_items[count] = new Sprite();
        dot_items[count].graphics.beginFill(0x141496, 1);
        dot_items[count].graphics.drawCircle(segment / 2 + (segment * i), segment / 2 + (segment * l), segment / 2);
        dot_items[count].graphics.endFill();
        addChild(dot_items[count]);
    }
}
for (var it: int = 0; it < nsquare; it++) {
    var fadeTime: Number = Math.random() * (basetime / 3) + basetime;
    tweens[it] = new Tween(dot_items[it], "alpha", Regular.easeInOut, 1, 0, fadeTime, true);
    function onFinish(e: TweenEvent): void {
        e.target.yoyo();
    }
    tweens[it].addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't really work" - Please elaborate. What is the current behavior, what is the expected behavior and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: it writes the sprites and starts the tween - so all 'dots' fade out at various speeds but only the very last one blinks after that.

Comment: i'm looking for a way that would let each sprite blink in a slightly different interval, say 1 at 1,2 sec; 2 at 1,4 sec; 3 at 1 sec; 4 at 1,2 sec.... and so on. durations randomly applied..

Comment: The simplest (albeit not the most performance-wise, but it will do for such a small amount of objects) way to approach this is to write a **Pixel** class that draws an 1x1 fill of given color inside itself than blinks it at a given rate. Next, you create and position the 40x40 matrix of **Pixel** instances providing them with random initial colors and blink rates.

Comment: thank you both. i'm not sure i understood the Pixel class suggestion. for the desired result it would have to be circles.

Comment: The shape of the objects is totally irrelevant. Draw circles, rectangles, pentagons, whatever. The OOP approach is only thing that matters.

Comment: i made it. mistake found